# Attach ToggleClass events to future elements in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have multiple Div elements rendered dynamically through a loop.

Am trying to,

1. Attach an onClick event to the dynamically rendered elements.
2. Toggle the class through the onClick function.

The class name has to be toggled only to the span element that is clicked. 
But the problem with the below code is, the class gets toggled to all the span elements rendered through this loop.

But I need to toggle the class only to the particular element that is clicked.

Though not the exact/complete code, the basic structure looks like this.,

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      classnm: 'collapsed',
    };
  }

func2 = event => {
  let currentClass = this.state.classnm;
  if(currentClass == 'collapsed') {
    this.setState({classnm: 'expanded'});
  }
  else {
    this.setState({classnm: 'collapsed'});
  }
};

render() {
    return (
        <div>
           <Iterate>{this.renderIndexColumn}</Iterate>             
        </div>
    );
  }

  // The below function gets called at least 10 times, rendering the below span element at least 10 times.

  renderIndexColumn = () => {
    return (
      <div>
      <span id={data.RefId} className = {this.state.classnm} onClick={(event) => {this.func2(event)}}>
          <i className="material-icons">arrow_right</i></span>
      </div>
    );
  };
```

If it is JQuery, I would have used ' on', 'this' to target the particular element & toggleClass.
  Am not sure how to do the same in React.

Can someone help to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to set `className` to `this.state.classnm`. Just do this instead:

```
<span id={data.RefId} className = 'collapsed'  ... />
```

And then your `func2` should be something like:

```
func2 = event => {
  event.target.classList.toggle('collapsed')
};
```

Comment: @Dexter, how about some response?

Comment: @ streletss , Thanks a lot.  It works. It attaches the class to the inner element.  Sorry about the delay in response.

Comment: I have one more question related to this but not part of the actual question. Is there a way , I could remove the added classes, if the particular element is hidden from the DOM.  Right now, the added classes stay with the element, even if it is hidden and reappears ( not re-rendering, just hidden temporarily from the DOM). Thanks

Comment: `[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.collapsed'), el => el.classList.remove('collapsed'))`